# How to use UITextField Delegate to modify behavior?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a ViewController with two `UITextFields` that I have as properties.

I have the following method that sets the max number of characters entered into both fields to be 3.  I want this method to set the limit for text field #1 to be 3, and for text field #2 to be 2.

I also have my `rightBarButtonItem` *disabled*, so I want it to be *enabled* only when both text fields have text entered.  Can anyone help me with this?

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSUInteger newLength = textField.text.length + string.length - range.length;

    return (newLength > 3) ? NO : YES;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of delegate method ,You can use following approach .It will work Fine.

```
BOOL isFirstTExtFieldValue; //To check whether textField has some Value.
BOOL isSecondTExtFieldValue;
UITextField * textField1;   //Assuming that you have already set the frames.
UITextField * textField2;
UIButton * button;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
isFirstTExtFieldValue=NO;  //Initially set the value to No.
isSecondTExtFieldValue=NO;

textField1.tag=1;
textField2.tag=2;

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
[textField1 addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

[textField2 addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

button.enabled=NO;
}

-(void)textFieldDidChange :(UITextField *)theTextField
{


if(theTextField.tag==1)
{
    if ([[textField1 text] length] > 3) {
        [textField1 setText:[[textField1 text]
                                          substringToIndex:3]];
    }
    else if([[textField1 text] length] >= 1)
    {
        isFirstTExtFieldValue=YES;
    }
    else
    {
        isFirstTExtFieldValue=NO;

    }

}
else if(theTextField.tag==2)
{
    if ([[textField2 text] length] > 2) {
        [textField2 setText:[[textField2 text]
                             substringToIndex:2]];
    }
    else if([[textField2 text] length] >= 1)
    {
        isSecondTExtFieldValue=YES;
    }
    else
    {
        isSecondTExtFieldValue=NO;

    }
}
if (isFirstTExtFieldValue && isSecondTExtFieldValue)
{
    button.enabled=YES;
}
else
{
     button.enabled=NO;
}

}
```

Happy Coding!! Cheers..!!

Answer (score 0):

Why not `if...else` condition inside the method.. Something like:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSUInteger newLength = textField.text.length + string.length - range.length;
    if(textField == textField1) // textField1 as your first UITExtfield
    {
            return (newLength > 3) ? NO : YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return (newLength > 2) ? NO : YES;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what about the second part of my question though? "I also have my rightBarButtonItem disabled, so I want it to be enabled only when both text fields have text entered. Can anyone help me with this?"

Answer (score 0):

You have the reference to your textfield in the method, so you can check it. Let's say you have textfield1 and textfield2 as IBOutlets, then you can test for it:

```
if (textField == textfield1) {
   //set maxLength to 3
} else {
   //set maxLength to 2
}
```